# Android SDK manager linux permission issue

Tags: android, linux, eclipse, netbeans, archlinux

The problem is I can't install anything with the sdk manager if I'm not root. The "android" tool runs but I get permissions error. However when I try to run it as root I get this:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.io.File.<init>(File.java:277)
at com.android.sdklib.internal.avd.AvdManager.parseAvdInfo(AvdManager.java:1616)
at com.android.sdklib.internal.avd.AvdManager.buildAvdList(AvdManager.java:1577)
at com.android.sdklib.internal.avd.AvdManager.<init>(AvdManager.java:350)
at com.android.sdklib.internal.avd.AvdManager.getInstance(AvdManager.java:373)
at com.android.sdklib.internal.repository.updater.UpdaterData.initSdk(UpdaterData.java:254)
at com.android.sdklib.internal.repository.updater.UpdaterData.<init>(UpdaterData.java:122)
at com.android.sdkuilib.internal.repository.SwtUpdaterData.<init>(SwtUpdaterData.java:61)
at com.android.sdkuilib.internal.repository.ui.SdkUpdaterWindowImpl2.<init>(SdkUpdaterWindowImpl2.java:104)
at com.android.sdkuilib.repository.SdkUpdaterWindow.<init>(SdkUpdaterWindow.java:88)
at com.android.sdkmanager.Main.showSdkManagerWindow(Main.java:407)
at com.android.sdkmanager.Main.doAction(Main.java:390)
at com.android.sdkmanager.Main.run(Main.java:150)
at com.android.sdkmanager.Main.main(Main.java:116)
```

I'm runnin Archlinux 64 bit btw

Comment: I put android studio set-up in home directory after downloading and this works just fine. never needed root level privileges. Give it a try and let me know the progress.

Comment: I only see a .exe on the website. Don't even know how I would install in root with pacman. Gonna check this, maybe that's a solution... But I'm running it as an user which has access and it's not working

Comment: Go down and in other download option you will find linux version for android studio. `.exe` doesnt work on linux. this link `https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html`.

Comment: Ok but how does that help? I can download the sdk and put it in /home but it will still try to write in /opt

Comment: My whole Android-studio set up is in home directory including sdk. In terminal i just have to call `maxx@Dzeko:~/Downloads/android-studio/bin$ sh studio.sh`. I am using it for 3-4 months now.

Answer (score 1):

Since it's installed in /opt dir, best way would be to create a user group, and add your user to his group :

```
# groupadd sdkusers
Add your user into this group:
# gpasswd -a <user> sdkusers
Change folders group.
# chown -R :sdkusers /opt/android-sdk/
Change permissions of the folder so the user that was just added to the group will be able to write in it:
# chmod -R g+w /opt/android-sdk/
```

[source](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Android#Android_SDK_core_components)

Comment: Yes I already did that but still I can't write when I use the sdk manager... I followed https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Android#Android_SDK_core_components so I have a sdkuser group, my user is added to it and I changed the permissions

Answer (score 0):

deleting the **.android** folder will do the trick.